# Going to plus if

Tags: future-time, will-vs-going-to

is it correct to ask

> What are you going to do if you lose your pants on the train?

Or maybe better to ask

> What are you going to do when you lose your pants on the train?

Thanks.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. (Although they would also both be a little strange to ask someone. Are they about to travel on a train known for causing people to lose their pants?)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JasonBassford - both sentences are grammatical. They have different meanings, though - the first (with *if*) leaves open the possibility that the listener might not lose their pants. The second (with *when*) assumes that the listener will definitely lose their pants and it’s just unclear at what time that will happen.